# My realtime map doesn't autorefresh

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, kml

I need help with a code from my work, it is a map (google,maps) with a kml, it is updated every 4 minutes time to the script extract the information to the bd, my problem is with the map. It doesn't refresh.

the map is here: 190.216.202.35/control/patios.html

and the kml is here: 190.216.202.35/control/refresh.kml

the map call a kml

all the code is correct but the page dont refresh the points not move until y "F5" the page

sorry for my English but I really need help

I have this but Is Not Enough

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var kmlLayerOptions = {map:map, preserveViewport:true}; //map:display kml layer on created map object called "map"; preserveViewport: preserve maps options


    var kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://190.216.202.35/control/refresh.kml?dummy="+(new Date()).getTime(),  kmlLayerOptions);}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: did you get over this?

Answer (score 0):

```
var refreshMilliseconds = 3000;
    var options = {
        frequency : refreshMilliseconds,
        enableHighAccuracy : true
    };
```

try to implement the code code in function watchUserLocation(),i am trying to upadte for every 3 sec